# How to publish a single .Net Core file update to IIS?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

I am just starting out with .Net Core 3 and only got as far as creating a new project in VS2019. Coming from ColdFusion, I could just select a newly developed file e.g. user.cfm and upload that to IIS. I don't have to upload the whole project.

How is this done in .Net Core? It seems to want to publish the whole "app" when not all of it is ready. I want to publish it in stages only. I also don't want to have to select every file that I want to publish each time - so if on the first "release" I have published most of the files then on the second update to the site I just want to select the new/update file to add to the site. Is this possible?

Comment: In my experience, using Web Deploy has "remembered" who last published the up and only deploys the new/changed files as long the the last person to deploy is the person doing the deploy now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't specify the exact files to upload, Web Deploy does only upload the new or changed files by default.
It's not explicitly stated prior to publish that that's what it's going to do, but a full publish does do incremental updates.

Comment: What if I have 5 files that are work-in-progress and I only want to publish one of them to live? How do I achieve that? In ColdFusion I just FTP upload the file that I want publishing because it doesn't compile code... it is an interpreted language.

Comment: You need to use some sort of source control like a local GIT repo to hold your changes in branches and only publish a branch that's ready to publish, otherwise (using Web Deploy), it's all going to be uploaded.

Comment: Is this the only way with .net? Don't you find this much more convoluted than interpreted languages like PHP or Python where the files themselves just run?

Comment: Not particularly, it's something we've always done and gotten used to doing on a daily basis. Our workflow has us complete discreet pieces of work against the whole project by branching off, doing the work in that branch, then merging back into the main branch with a pull request which also serves as a peer review and then publishing when it's ready.
This helps enormously when it comes to fault finding and rolling back to prior versions as change history is comprehensive.
Have a look at this link for useful information on "Why Git" https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/why-git

Comment: What happens if you branch off to do some work, but then an urgent bug is detected in a master branch file and you need to update just that one file and upload it to production without including any of your new developments?

Comment: You branch off from Master and create a "hotfix" branch. Do your work in that branch, then merge those commits back into Master to deploy assuming some form of UAT. Pull those commits also into your current dev branch and work down the chain. It's difficult to explain branching and merging in comments along but it can be done easily when explained with graphics - I'm sure there are better demonstrations for using GIT than I can do here. => https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow